# Scala implicit dynamic casting

Tags: android, scala

I whould like to create a scala Views helper for Android

Using this combination of trait and class

```
class ScalaView(view: View) {
  def onClick(action: View => Any) =
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
      def onClick(view: View) {
        action(view)
      }
    })
}

trait ScalaViewTrait {
  implicit def view2ScalaView(view: View) =
    new ScalaView(view)
}
```

I'm able to write onClick() like so

```
class MainActivity extends Activity with ScalaViewTrait {
//....
val textView = new TextView(this)
textView.onClick(v => v.asInstanceOf[TextView] setText ("asdas"))
}
```

My concern is that i want to avoid casting `v` to `TextView`

`v` will always be `TextView` if is applied to a `TextView` `LinearLayout` if applied to `LinearLayout` and so on.

Is there any way that `v` gets dynamic casted to whatever view is applied?

Just started with Scala and i need your help with this.

**UPDATE**

Solved see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it. 
Here is how

```
trait ScalaViewTrait {
  implicit def view2ScalaView[T <: View](view: T) =
    new ScalaView[T](view)
}

class ScalaView[T <: View](view: T) {
  def onClick(action: T => Any) =
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
      def onClick(view: View) {
        action(view.asInstanceOf[T])
      }
    })
}
```

And now i can write onClick like this

```
textView.onClick(v => v.setText("asdsa"))
```

`v` is actually a `TextView` when `onClick` is applied to a `TextView`

PS. Maybe i'll write a bunch of helpers and publish them on GitHub. <3 Scala

Comment: @agilesteel No because onClickListener needs a View param and onclick action needs a T param

Comment: I meant when you call action you do it like this: `action(view.asInstanceOf[T])` does `action(view: T)` also work?

Comment: @agilesteel no because onClickListener doesn't implement onClick(T<:View) but requires onClick(View)

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that given the Android API, it's simply not possible for you to have full type safety *and* the convenience of defining an action that only works on the relevant subclass of `View`.

Your approach sacrifices type safety, and drexin's sacrifices (some) convenience. Like you, I'd be willing to give up type safety in this situation, since it's reasonable to expect good behavior from the Android library, but I'd encapsulate the unpleasantness a little differently.

First I'd define a wrapper for `OnClickListener` like this:

```
case class MyOnClickListener[V <: View](action: V => Any)
  extends OnClickListener {
  def onClick(view: View) = try action(view.asInstanceOf[V]) catch {
    case e: ClassCastException =>
      throw new RuntimeException("This should never happen!", e)
  }
}
```

And then forget that `OnClickListener` exists (or at least never use it anywhere else in my code). Now all the non-type safe stuff is bundled up in one place, and my `ScalaView` class is clean, for example:

```
class ScalaView[T <: View](view: T) {
  def onClick(action: T => Any) =
    view.setOnClickListener(MyOnClickListener(action))
}
```

You're likely to run into other places where you need this kind of wrapper, and this approach allows you to keep all the ugly casts, etc. carefully contained in one place, instead of scattered throughout your code.

Comment: Thank you for your time. You made also @drexin's point more clear to me. My purpose here is to make a bunch of  helpers (and name it library) that ads implicits methods to all android View and subclasses. So for that matter the castings will not be scatted around, but just in the "library"

Comment: Also [off topic and applies to all] i'm very happy to see that scala has a (very) active community.. at least here

Answer (score 1):

You could instead of casting it simply pattern match on it:

```
// ...
textView.onClick {
  case v: TextView => v.setText("foobar")
  case v => log.error("Expected TextView got %s.".format(v.getClass))
}
```

Comment: thank you but this only ads more boilerplate. I prefer a generic solution

Comment: I'm no Scala expert (by far) but what is not safe about the solution I gave?

Comment: The thing is, that nothing ensures, that the View you get passed into `onClick` is of type T. It could be anything. It will most likely be of type `T`, as normally you get the instance of the view, that the handler is called on passed into it, but there is no guarantee. Custom controls could do anything here. It is unlikely, that this will ever happen, but it could.

Comment: view2ScalaView and ScalaView cannot be applied to nothing else but a "extends View" instance. If "T<:View" was "T" then i could write "1".onClick(...) but "T<:View" assures that T will be a View. Also OnClickListener will always return the same view as <view>.setOnClickListener was applied. And <view> is always T (that extends View) I'm i missing something here? can you provide an example of view not being an instance of T or T not being a View? Ty

Comment: @weakwire: The problem is that from the perspective of the compiler, `onClick` could be given any arbitrary `View` (which isn't necessarily a `T`). _You_ know this should never happen, but you can't prove it to the compiler. You can use a cast, but that's essentially just bossing the compiler around, and by definition not type safe.

Comment: Ah I see your point. Like @TravisBrown said i'll, have to trust the Android SDK. Receive my upvotes in you comments